# elFinder - FTP Class File Missing / Error

Tags: ftp, elfinder

So I downloaded the library from http://elfinder.org/ (v.2.0-rc1) and it is missing the FTP class file.

I tried downloading the library directly from gitHub and got a different version for some reason (v2.x). When I copy the FTP class file over from there (or try using that entire build), I get an error anytime I try to include the file in the connector.php file:

"Unable to connect to backend."

(Yes, I have the correct FTP info entered into the connector.php file. The error is generated whenever I attempt to INCLUDE the FTP class file. If I don't include it, I can access the local files just fine.)

Where is the correct file or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you must include all php files in connector.php and ftp class too